# RESTful API database authentication, which verb?

Tags: api, rest, authentication

I need an API call to authenticate a login. We have a database with a users table, and we're building a front-end, with an API in the middle. The front-end takes a username and password from the user, and we need to authenticate these credentials against the database using the API.

So we have:

1. Request to authenticate the user
2. Response to indicate authenticated or not

### Request

I'm guessing the request should be a `GET`, as `POST` is for creating and `PUT` is for updating, and we're doing neither of those.

We need to send the username and password to the server, and since we're using `GET`, am I correct in saying we can only use query string parameters or headers to send the data..?

I don't think query string parameters is right for passwords etc, so that leaves headers for the request:

```
GET https://my-local-api-server/authenticate HTTP/1.1
username: my.username
password: mypassword
```

Is this a correct RESTful request, sending data to the server for authenticating..?

### Response

For the response, should we only use the response status code (200 or 401), or should we send JSON containing the outcome of the authentication request..?

```
{
    "authenticated": true,
    "error": ""
}
```

or

```
{
    "authenticated": false,
    "error": "Some error message..."
}
```

Which is the correct RESTful response..? Or should it be both..?

**UPDATE**

My question wasn't great, so I need to clarify.

I shouldn't have used a public URL in my example above, this is actually a local server and local API, which will never be used externally, and will only be consumed by other local apps internally. If this ever changes we can revisit what we're doing.

I think I confused things a bit by not being clear about the authentication I'm doing. I'm authenticating a user (a real world person) against a database. I'm not authenticating the usage of the API.

The apps we're going to be writing are all internal and won't need to authenticate to use the API. No API keys etc.

So... I'm taking a real world person, and checking to see if they should have access to our app, I'm not checking to see if our app has access to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An overview of authentication in REST

In REST APIs, when accessing protected resources that require authentication, every request must contain all necessary data to be properly authenticated/authorized. And authentication data (credentials) should belong to the standard HTTP [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header:

> [**4.2.  Authorization**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2)
>
> The `Authorization` header field allows a user agent to authenticate
> itself with an origin server -- usually, but not necessarily, after
> receiving a `401` (Unauthorized) response.  Its value consists of
> credentials containing the authentication information of the user
> agent for the realm of the resource being requested.
>
> ```
> Authorization = credentials
> ```
>
> [...]

Please note that the name of this HTTP header is *unfortunate* because it carries *authentication* data instead of *authorization*. Anyways, this is the standard header for sending *credentials* in the HTTP protocol.

REST applications are supposed to be stateless, so there must not be *session state* stored on server side. Instead, the session state must be handled *entirely by the client*, as defined in the Roy T. Fielding's [dissertation about REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm):

> [**5.1.3 Stateless**](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3)
>
> [...] each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. [...]

Hence, it doesn't matter the verb you are using, if you are performing a request to a protected resource, the request should contain the authentication data.

### Basic authentication

A common approach for securing REST APIs is to use the [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2):

> [**2. The 'Basic' Authentication Scheme**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617#section-2)
>
> The Basic authentication scheme is based on the model that the client
> needs to authenticate itself with a user-id and a password for each
> protection space ("realm"). [...] The server will service the request only if it can validate
> the user-id and password for the protection space applying to the
> requested resource.
>
> [...]
>
> To receive authorization, the client
>
> 1. obtains the user-id and password from the user,
> 2. constructs the user-pass by concatenating the user-id, a single
>    colon (":") character, and the password,
> 3. encodes the user-pass into an octet sequence,
> 4. and obtains the basic-credentials by encoding this octet sequence
>    using [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) into a sequence of [US-ASCII
>    characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20).
>
> [...]
>
> If the user agent wishes to send the user-id "Aladdin" and password
> "open sesame", it would use the following header field:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
> ```
>
> [...]

### Token based authentication

Another approach that is taking place is token based authentication. In this approach, you basically exchange hard credentials (username and password) for a token that the client must send in every request. In this approach, you can used `POST` to perform the authentication, sending the credentials in the request payload:

```
POST /api/authentication HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

If the authentication was successful, return a [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) status code along with a token in the response payload:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "authenticationToken": "<token goes here>"
}
```

Otherwise, if the credentials are invalid, return a [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1).

It's important to note that *tokens are the credentials* that will be used to authenticate the subsequent requests. So, tokens should be sent in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header too:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token goes here>
```

Comment: While this would work, we're not creating anything so I'm not convinced about using `POST`.

Comment: `POST` is a *catch all* verb and works for authentication as well.

Comment: @StephenLast In the REST APIs, every request to a protect resource must contain the authentication. The approach I've mentioned in my answer applies for situations you are exchanging hard credentials (username and password) for a token, for example.

Comment: Many thanks for all this info, it's very useful. I've added an update to my question. With the update in mind, do you think the token based auth (`POST` with JSON) is what I should be using..?

Comment: @StephenLast The Basic Authentication Scheme is just fine for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The most standard way to send username and password via HTTP to an API is using a Basic Auth header.

For the response, you should definitely use the proper HTTP status codes (such as Forbidden), but you can still include a JSON payload with more information in the body.

Comment: What verb should I use when sending the Basic Auth header..? The other answer so far (from Cássio Mazzochi Molin) suggests using `POST` rather than `GET`.

Comment: What is the result of the authenticate call? Do you get a freshly minted session token back? If so, `POST` sounds better. If it is just checking if the password is correct, then `GET`. But what would that be useful for in itself? OTOH, if you are just sending credentials to every API call, it does not need to be a separate request at all.

Comment: At the moment, it's one call to authenticate someone, no session is created. If we do create a session then yes, I understand that `POST` makes sense.